# Expanding per-person cumulative variable to time-interval variable

Tags: stata

I have dataset which shows how people spent their 30 minutes in 10-minute interval.

```
Person     cumulative_time   Activity
A              10             Game
A              30             Eat
B              10             Sleep
B              20             Game
B              30             Sleep

which means person A did gaming during the first 10 minutes, 
and eating during the next 20 minutes, 
and person B was sleeping for the first 10 min, 
gaming for the next 10 min, and sleeping for the last 10 mins.
```

I want to restructure the dataset. Each row will be each unique person.

Then, each column will be each time interval like this.

```
Person          time10    time20         time30
 A             Game         Eat           Eat
 B             Sleep        Game          Sleep
```

I know I can use "collapse" to make person unique but I don't know how this can be used for my purpose. The "reshape" command does something similar but again I cannot figure out how to use it to do what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Reshape is the way to solve this problem. Something like this may accomplish what you need.

```
clear
input str1 Person int cumulative_time str8 Activity
A              10             Game
A              30             Eat
B              10             Sleep
B              20             Game
B              30             Sleep
end
rename Activity time
reshape wide time, i(Person) j(cumulative_time)
replace time20 = time10 if missing(time20)
replace time30 = time20 if missing(time30)
list, clean
```

If your problem had many cumulative_time values, not just three, I would solve the problem of missing values in a different way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But your code results in somewhat different answer than the outcome I wanted. It should be Game, Eat, Eat. Not Game Game Eat

Comment: You're free to make the trivial changes necessary to my code to make it meet your needs - read the code and figure out what the commands do, then fix them.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the William Lisowski answer, here is an approach using `tsset` and `tsfill` commands:

```
clear
input str1 Person int cumulative_time str8 Activity
A              10             Game
A              30             Eat
B              10             Sleep
B              20             Game
B              30             Sleep
end
rename Activity time

egen id = group(Person)
tsset id cumulative_time, delta(10)
tsfill, full

bysort id : replace Person = Person[_n-1] if Person==""
bysort id : replace time= time[_n+1] if time==""
drop id

reshape wide time, i(Person) j(cumulative_time)
list, clean
```

Which outputs:

```
       Person   time10   time20   time30  
  1.        A     Game      Eat      Eat  
  2.        B    Sleep     Game    Sleep
```